# Can I secure my node API with Auth0 using only a client?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, jwt, auth0

I have a node.js API and a Vue.js client application. I'd like users of the client application to login using Auth0's Lock widget, which should generate a JWT that the client can use to query the API via the `Authorization` header. The API would verify the JWT using what I assume would be the "client secret" from the Auth0 dashboard. This would be very convenient because you can even deploy my app to heroku with the Auth0 add-on and it will generate the"Client ID and secret" for you.

Trouble is, the Lock widget retrieves what I believe is known as an "opaque access token" rather than a JWT. My API doesn't know how to read or verify this token, desire having the "client secret."

I believe this may be a relatively recent change and Auth0 recommends setting up an "API" in the Auth0 dashboard and then specifying it as the `auth.params.audience` in the Lock widget request. But this approach has been heavily more complex. The `audience` property isn't even documented in the Lock widget docs, you have to learn about and setup jwks (or use hs256 even though they recommend against it), the users are asked whether they want to share their account they created for your site with...your site..., and heroku can't set up the "API" for you like it can the "Client" - anyone who clicks "deploy to heroku" would have to set up the "API" in the Auth0 dashboard manually.

I hope I've missed something and it's possible to authenticate the basic way I've described in my first paragraph. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Yes, essentially you are correct. Define an API in the Auth0 Dashboard, and send the audience param with your login request. The audience should match the "identifier" of the API.  See docs here - https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth

Comment: Thanks, but per my third paragraph above, I'm wondering if there's a simpler way, just using the "client?"

Comment: The API approach takes 5 mins when familiar with the steps. It is very simple, and offers you the ability to define scopes on your API. The approach also has OIDC Conformance.  Legacy approaches once approached this by sending the ID Token to the API but that has many problems and should be discouraged. Parts like JWKS should all be abstracted behind a JS library - have you tried the Auth0 Quickstarts?

Comment: Yes I have read several of them. I've been working on this for 4 days straight now - I haven't found it as simple as I expected, and I write front end JavaScript and node code everyday :-/ how can it be simple when the audience param for lock isn't even documented? Is there a way to do it without using an "API" in the Auth0 dashboard?

Comment: You should define an API via auth0 api / dashboard if you intend to to receive a JWT access token whose subject is the API.